# How to change this Ext.Net example to use Sql instead of Linq?

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatasource, ext.net, linqdatasource

I am going by [this example](http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Data_with_Details/Form_Details/) and trying to have it use a `SqlDataSource` instead of `LinqDataSource`. I can get the data to display in the table, but the form does not fill with the data when I select a row. I think these are the relevant bits of code:

```
protected void RowSelect(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
{
    string employeeID = e.ExtraParams["EmployeeID"];

    Employee empl = Employee.GetEmployee(int.Parse(employeeID));

    this.FormPanel1.SetValues(new {
        empl.EmployeeID,
        empl.FirstName,                          
        empl.LastName,
        ...........
    });
}
```

And

```
<SelectionModel>
    <ext:RowSelectionModel runat="server" Mode="Single">
        <DirectEvents>
            <Select OnEvent="RowSelect" Buffer="250">
                <EventMask ShowMask="true" Target="CustomTarget" CustomTarget="#{FormPanel1}" />
                <ExtraParams>
                    <ext:Parameter Name="EmployeeID" Value="record.getId()" Mode="Raw" />
                </ExtraParams>
            </Select>
        </DirectEvents>
    </ext:RowSelectionModel>
</SelectionModel>

protected void Store1_Refresh(object sender, StoreReadDataEventArgs e)
{
    this.Store1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick:

```
<SelectionModel>
    <ext:RowSelectionModel ID="RowSelectionModel1" runat="server" Mode="Single">
        <Listeners>
            <Select Handler="#{FormPanel1}.getForm().loadRecord(record);" />
        </Listeners>
    </ext:RowSelectionModel>
</SelectionModel>
```